# Permission override after stat is called

Tags: c, permissions, system-calls, fuse, stat

Hi I'm writing "net raid fs" with FUSE.

So when syscall `getattr` is called, I'm sending it to server, server is calling `stat(path, stbuf)` syscall and it sets `stbuf` as it should do. After that I'm returning this `stbuf` to client (with socket connection) and client handles it and everything is working okay.

But here is the problem: I want `stbuf->st_mode` (AKA permissions) always to be 0777, so I'm doing `stbuf->st_mode = 0777;` and after that sending this `struct` to client (as I did above). And program kind of freezes (server [or client] stops receiving syscalls properly).

What to do?

Comment: I am not on top of this, but you should post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why changing the value of a struct member would cause a problem like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `st_mode` member includes more than just the permissions, it also includes the file type (directory, fifo, device special file, etc.). If you simply assign `0777` to it, you'll remove the type information. You should just overwrite the permission bits.

```
stbuf->mode |= 0777;
```

From the documentation:

> ```
>  The status information word st_mode has the following bits:
>
>  #define S_IFMT 0170000           /* type of file */
>  #define        S_IFIFO  0010000  /* named pipe (fifo) */
>  #define        S_IFCHR  0020000  /* character special */
>  #define        S_IFDIR  0040000  /* directory */
>  #define        S_IFBLK  0060000  /* block special */
>  #define        S_IFREG  0100000  /* regular */
>  #define        S_IFLNK  0120000  /* symbolic link */
>  #define        S_IFSOCK 0140000  /* socket */
>  #define        S_IFWHT  0160000  /* whiteout */
>  #define S_ISUID 0004000  /* set user id on execution */
>  #define S_ISGID 0002000  /* set group id on execution */
>  #define S_ISVTX 0001000  /* save swapped text even after use */
>  #define S_IRUSR 0000400  /* read permission, owner */
>  #define S_IWUSR 0000200  /* write permission, owner */
>  #define S_IXUSR 0000100  /* execute/search permission, owner */
> ```

Comment: But aren't there only 3 bits per category anyway? Not my DV.

Comment: I've added an excerpt from the documentation showing that it also contains the `S_IFMT` field that contains the file type.